# Meteor 1.5.2: Cordova [Error: spawn EACCES]

Tags: cordova, meteor

When building a Meteor Cordova app this error occurs ("EACCES"). It only happens for the Cordova app. It supposedly has to do with permissions, so I recursively changed CHMOD to 777 to all subfolders. This did not help and Im all out of ideas.

```
While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /Users/fullhdpixel/Projects/MyRoutes/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --device
   { [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
   'Error: spawn EACCES\n    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)\n
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/raw/4xbxJSC5

If you need a reproduction let me know, but I think this is something you can help with without a reproduction. Here is the cordova-plugin list

```
cordova-custom-config@4.0.2
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.3.0
cordova-plugin-device@1.1.6
cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3
cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.4.3
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1
cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@1.4.2
cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.3
cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.3
cordova-plugin-tts@0.2.3
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine@1.1.3
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@5.2.0
cordova-universal-links-plugin@1.2.1
cordova-plugin-console@1.0.7
cordova-plugin-flurryanalytics@1.4.3
```

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @Stephan yes its fixed https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9073